# Hibernate NoSuchFieldError INSTANCE but only with Struts 1?

Tags: java, hibernate, struts

I'm new to Java and Hibernate (being a Rails and C# developer).  Anyway, I have a test program that works fine with Hibernate but my actual web app (Struts 1) crashes with:

`SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE`

I am using:

`Hibernate 3.6.1 with Annotations`

`Struts 1 with Apache Tiles`

`C3P0 connection pool`

Here is the program that actually **WORKS**.  It's a part of the main project.  Just a simple JAVA test.

```
public class TestUser {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    String queryString = "from User where UserName = 'Quake'";
    Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);

    User quake = (User)query.uniqueResult();
    session.getTransaction().commit();

    System.out.println( quake.getEmail() );
    System.out.println( "Active? " + quake.isActive() );


    UserRepository userRepo = new UserRepository();

    System.out.println( "User Quake: " + userRepo.findAll().get(0).getEmail() );

  }
}
```

Works just fine.  Outputs a little sample data.

Now, when I try to do the same thing in Struts, I get the exception.  This is what does **NOT WORK**:

```
public class ListUsers extends org.apache.struts.action.Action {

  /* forward name="success" path="" */
  private static final String SUCCESS = "success";

/**
 * This is the action called from the Struts framework.
 * @param mapping The ActionMapping used to select this instance.
 * @param form The optional ActionForm bean for this request.
 * @param request The HTTP Request we are processing.
 * @param response The HTTP Response we are processing.
 * @throws java.lang.Exception
 * @return
 */
@Override
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {


    List<String> listMsg = new ArrayList<String>();

    listMsg.add("Message A");
    listMsg.add("Message B");
    listMsg.add("Message C");
    listMsg.add("Message D");

    request.setAttribute("listMsg", listMsg);



    UserRepository userRepo = new UserRepository();  // CRASHES HERE (see HibernateUtil)
    String email = userRepo.first().getEmail();


    return mapping.findForward(SUCCESS);
  }
}
```

This is my HibernateUtil class:

```
public class HibernateUtil {

  private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

  private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {
        // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
        Configuration config = new Configuration();  // THIS LINE CRASHES IN STRUTS

        // Add annotated classes
        config.addAnnotatedClass(User.class);

        config.configure();
        return config.buildSessionFactory();

    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed.  WTFQNIL: " + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
  }

  public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
  }
}
```

The `Configuration config = new Configuration()` line in the `HibernateUtil` is the line that crashes in Struts but not the test app.

Here is the complete exception dump:

```
Feb 24, 2011 9:51:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
at org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry.<init>(BasicTypeRegistry.java:94)
at org.hibernate.type.TypeResolver.<init>(TypeResolver.java:59)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:249)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:300)
at com.kencogroup.kkms.struts.utilities.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:22)
at com.kencogroup.kkms.struts.utilities.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:17)
at com.kencogroup.dao.repositories.UserRepository.first(UserRepository.java:33)
at com.kencogroup.kkms.struts.actions.ListUsers.execute(ListUsers.java:52)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:425)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:381)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:213)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:171)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:381)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:859)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1555)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It looks like you have several versions of Hibernate jars in the classpath.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of my JARS for Hibernate.  I created a global library.   http://dl.dropbox.com/u/471665/jars.png

Comment: +1 for pointing me in the general area.  Turns out, I had an old version of hibernate-annotations which I didn't need because Hibernate 3.6 comes with annotation support????  Anyway, works now.

Comment: @cbmeeks: Exactly, that was the cause.

Comment: Just to add that in our case (unrelated to Struts) the culprits were "hibernate-annotations-3.4.0.GA" and "hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final" which could be safely removed for "hibernate-3.6.8.Final". Having this answer on SE greatly reduced the debugging time.

Comment: I had 2 jars `hibernate-core-3.5.6-Final.jar` and `hibernate3.jar` just I removed last one and it works fine -thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Removing these two dependency worked for me.**

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.ga</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
    </dependency>
```

**These are my hibernate dependencies.**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>3.17.1-GA</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm-all</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>antlr</groupId>
    <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

@axtavt  says right.
I know you already solved the problem, I post my comments as it might be helpful to other people.

If you are using maven dependencies, say you already have your own hibernate dependency. And later, another dependency (like org.codehaus.jackson or drools-spring) is added to the pom. It might cause this error because org.codehaus.jackson and drools-spring have their own dependency on a different version hibernate. exclude hibernate when you add org.codehaus.jackson or drools-spring would solve the prob.