# NoSuchFieldError while implementing Twilio on Google app engine Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, twilio, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I was following [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/sms/twilio) tutorial for implementing Twilio on Google app engine
java project using Google endpoints framework. So, I tried the latest version of Twilio and implemented its 7.1.0 version. The servlet code is

```
`public class SendSmsServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;




    @Override
    public void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException,
        ServletException {
      final String twilioAccountSid = System.getenv("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID");
      final String twilioAuthToken = System.getenv("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN");
      final String twilioNumber = System.getenv("TWILIO_NUMBER");
      final String toNumber = (String) req.getParameter("to");
      if (toNumber == null) {
        resp.getWriter()
            .print("Please provide the number to message in the \"to\" query string parameter.");
        return;
      }

          Twilio.init(twilioAccountSid, twilioAuthToken);
String sms="This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs?";
            Message message = Message.creator(new PhoneNumber(toNumber),
                    new PhoneNumber("+1 904-222-6016 "), 
                    "This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs?").create();

        resp.getWriter().print(message.getSid());

    }
}
```

When a call this endpoint with relevant number it gives the flowing error

```
    java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit> (SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:144)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.getDefaultRegistry (PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:109)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init> (PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:116)
at com.twilio.http.NetworkHttpClient.<init> (NetworkHttpClient.java:45)
at com.twilio.http.TwilioRestClient$Builder.<init> (TwilioRestClient.java:66)
at com.twilio.Twilio.getRestClient (Twilio.java:118)
at com.twilio.base.Creator.create (Creator.java:45)
at in.prago.merchant.servlet.SendSmsServlet.service (SendSmsServlet.java:58)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service (HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle (ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter (ObjectifyFilter.java:48)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter (ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter (SaveSessionFilter.java:37)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter (JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter (TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle (ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle (SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle (SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle (ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle (WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle (AppVersionHandlerMap.java:257)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle (HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle (Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest (HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete (HttpConnection.java:923)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable (RpcRequestParser.java:76)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle (HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest (JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest (JavaRuntime.java:657)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest (JavaRuntime.java:619)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run (JavaRuntime.java:589)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext (TraceContext.java:453)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run (TraceContext.java:460)
at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext (CurrentContext.java:293)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref (TraceContext.java:319)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext (TraceContext.java:311)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run (TraceContext.java:457)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run (ThreadGroupPool.java:263)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:745)
```

My pom.xml is somewhat like this

```
    <project>
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

        <groupId>com.example.echo</groupId>
        <artifactId>echo</artifactId>

        <parent>
            <artifactId>appengine-doc-samples</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <relativePath>../..</relativePath>
        </parent>

        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

            <endpoints.framework.version>2.0.7</endpoints.framework.version>
            <endpoints.management.version>1.0.3</endpoints.management.version>

            <endpoints.project.id>MY_PROJECT_KEY</endpoints.project.id>
            <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
            <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
            <appengine.maven.plugin.version>1.3.1</appengine.maven.plugin.version>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.objectify/objectify -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.objectify</groupId>
        <artifactId>objectify</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.17</version>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.twilio.sdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>twilio</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <version>7.1.0</version>

    </dependency>

            <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.endpoints</groupId>
                <artifactId>endpoints-framework</artifactId>
                <version>${endpoints.framework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.endpoints</groupId>
                <artifactId>endpoints-management-control-appengine-all</artifactId>
                <version>${endpoints.management.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <profiles>
            <profile>
                <id>GetSwaggerDoc</id>
                <activation>
                    <property>
                        <name>GetSwaggerDoc</name>
                    </property>
                </activation>
                <build>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>1.4.0</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <includePluginDependencies>true</includePluginDependencies>
                                <mainClass>com.google.api.server.spi.tools.EndpointsTool</mainClass>
                                <arguments>
                                    <argument>get-swagger-doc</argument>
                                    <argument>--hostname=echo-api.endpoints.${endpoints.project.id}.cloud.goog</argument>
                                    <argument>--war=target/echo-1.0-SNAPSHOT</argument>
                                    <argument>com.example.echo.Echo</argument>
                                </arguments>
                            </configuration>
                            <dependencies>
                                <dependency>
                                    <groupId>com.google.endpoints</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>endpoints-framework-tools</artifactId>
                                    <version>${endpoints.framework.version}</version>
                                     <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
                                </dependency>
                                <dependency>
                                    <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
                                    <version>1.9.30</version>
                                </dependency>
                            </dependencies>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </build>
            </profile>
        </profiles>

        <build>
            <!-- for hot reload of the web application-->
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <webResources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                                <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                            </resource>
                        </webResources>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                    <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${appengine.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

Looking at the stack trace I think there is some SSL issue. I new to Google cloud. Please guide to get over this issue.

Comment: Stack Overflow shows that this is normally caused by [conflicting dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21622885/java-lang-nosuchfielderror-instance). Have you taken a look through these questions and their answers?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.twilio.sdk</groupId>
  <artifactId>twilio</artifactId>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <version>7.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

With:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.twilio.sdk</groupId>
  <artifactId>twilio-java-sdk</artifactId>
  <version>6.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```