# Jira communication using java

Tags: java, jira, jira-plugin, jira-rest-java-api

I am trying to communicate with jira using Java but i am facing an exception as shown below

```
xception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.DefaultClientAsyncConnectionFactory.createHttpResponseFactory(DefaultClientAsyncConnectionFactory.java:105)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.DefaultClientAsyncConnectionFactory.<init>(DefaultClientAsyncConnectionFactory.java:74)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.DefaultClientAsyncConnectionFactory.<clinit>(DefaultClientAsyncConnectionFactory.java:62)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingClientAsyncConnectionManager.createClientAsyncConnectionFactory(PoolingClientAsyncConnectionManager.java:96)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingClientAsyncConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingClientAsyncConnectionManager.java:72)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.DefaultHttpClient$2.<init>(DefaultHttpClient.java:117)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.DefaultHttpClient.<init>(DefaultHttpClient.java:115)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousHttpClientFactory.createClient(AsynchronousHttpClientFactory.java:53)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.create(AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.java:35)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.java:42)
    at jira.JiraCommunicate.main(JiraCommunicate.java:33)
```

Exception i am facing at this line 
 JiraRestClient client = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(uri, JIRA_ADMIN_USERNAME, JIRA_ADMIN_PASSWORD);

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;


import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.JiraRestClient;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.JiraRestClientFactory;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.BasicProject;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.Comment;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.Issue;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.SearchResult;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.Transition;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.User;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.input.FieldInput;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.input.TransitionInput;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory;
import com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promise;

public class JiraCommunicate {

     private static final String JIRA_URL = "";
        private static final String JIRA_ADMIN_USERNAME = "";
        private static final String JIRA_ADMIN_PASSWORD = "";

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            // Construct the JRJC client
            //System.out.println(String.format("Logging in to %s with username '%s' and password '%s'", JIRA_URL, JIRA_ADMIN_USERNAME, JIRA_ADMIN_PASSWORD));
            JiraRestClientFactory factory = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory();
            URI uri = new URI(JIRA_URL);
            JiraRestClient client = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(uri, JIRA_ADMIN_USERNAME, JIRA_ADMIN_PASSWORD);

            // Invoke the JRJC Client
            Promise<User> promise = client.getUserClient().getUser("admin");
            User user = promise.claim();

            for (BasicProject project : client.getProjectClient().getAllProjects().claim()) {
                System.out.println(project.getKey() + ": " + project.getName());
            }

            Promise<SearchResult> searchJqlPromise = client.getSearchClient().searchJql("project = MYPURRJECT AND status in (Closed, Completed, Resolved) ORDER BY assignee, resolutiondate");

            for (Issue issue : searchJqlPromise.claim().getIssues()) {
                System.out.println(issue.getSummary());
            }

            // Print the result
            System.out.println(String.format("Your admin user's email address is: %s\r\n", user.getEmailAddress()));

            // Done
            System.out.println("Example complete. Now exiting.");
            System.exit(0);
        }


    }
```

> Blockquote

Please i need your help..I want to communicate Jira to upload or download Story or create bugs..

Comment: Do not attempt to post an image of the stack trace. Copy and paste the text.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106520/hibernate-nosuchfielderror-instance-but-only-with-struts-1 helps?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTPClient Example - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22330848/httpclient-example-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-nosuchfielderror-inst)

Comment: No ..its different...i am getting exception due to this line.
JiraRestClient client = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(uri, JIRA_ADMIN_USERNAME, JIRA_ADMIN_PASSWORD);

Comment: I also got the same error at the same position of the code.